# Bash command to create a new file and its parent directories if necessary

Tags: bash, shell

With the `-p` (`--parents`)  option, `mkdir` creates parent directories if necessary.

`touch`,  `vim` or `>` can create new files in bash, but only when the parent directories exist.

**How to create a new file and its parent directories if necessary, in one command?** Just like what the `-p` does for `mkdir`

Comment: Accepted answer isn't in bash or one line?

Comment: @MartinKonecny No. My intention was to ask for a `prime` command. Seems there is no such command. So I just accepted the earliest answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

install is your friend:

```
install -Dv /dev/null some/new/path/base-filename
```

Comment: that's what I want! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note: `make -p` does not change itself or subfolders if it exists, but `install /dev/null DEST` will truncate(empty) the file if it is already there.

Comment: Thanks, this helped :D Btw, you can skip -v flag.

Comment: Beware this creates by default executables for all, 755. Change it with `--mode=644`

Answer (score 17):

Here's a shell *function*:

```
mkfileP() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" || return; touch "$1"; }

# Sample call
mkfileP "./newSubDir/test.txt" && echo 'created or touched' || echo 'failure'
```

You can place it in your shell profile, for instance.

Alternatively, implement it as a *script* (add error handling and command-line help as needed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" || exit
touch "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently created a script directly for this purpose: https://gist.github.com/zinovyev/1f8caf9e886de610e2dd2c22a4ef7d69

Here're several examples of how it works:

```sh
$ tt foo/bar/file  # => Will create a file "/current/path/foo/bar/file"
```

```sh
$ tt foo/bar/dir/ # => Will create a directory "/current/path/foo/bar/dir"
```

Notice the `/` at the end of the path. That is how it determines whether the last chunk of the path should be a directory or a file.